# Does changing quests give you all waypoints?

Tags: diablo-iii

When I switch quests in Diablo 3 from one quest to another, I noted that I only have waypoints up until that point.  Does that list include all waypoints up to there, or only those I've previously discovered?  Unfortunately I didn't take note of which I had and hadn't discovered before jumping between quests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes changing quests gives you all relevant waypoints up until that point.  You usually run into them anyway so it's hard to skip them, even intentionally.